# Why php print "b1" in such code

Tags: php

```
<?php print("a")."b".print("с"); ?>
```

Result: **сab1**

Why php print "b1" in this code

Comment: Because the print() function has a return code! WTF? RTFM!

Comment: Yes! But it is not print(print("a")."b".print("с"));

Comment: why you use print instead of echo?

Comment: `print()` is a language construct and doesn't require brackets. Hence, `("a")."b".print("с");` is treated as one big argument.

Comment: i'm using echo.... but this code.. only for ьн self-development

Comment: @Pekka웃 you should add that as an answer, it's the only one that explains why "b1" is printed out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Equates to:

1. print("c").... output the value "c" and return a value of 1 to
   indicate success
2. print "a", concatenated with "b", concatenated with
   the result of print("c") (which is "1") giving `cab1`

Comment: I think that `print("c")` is evaluated *after* `"a"` and `"b"` are concatenated (i.e. evaluation is from left to right),  but it doesn't really matter for the outcome.

Comment: Thank you. My code equals print"a"."b".print "с"